# Ideal sheaf is aquasi-coherent sheaf of ideals.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme, For any closed subscheme $Y$ of $X$, the corresponding ideal $I_Y$ given by the kernel of the morphism $i^{\#}:\mathcal{O}_x\rightarrow i_{*}\mathcal{O}_y$ is quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on X.

I´m reading something about Tools for birrational geometry, and this is a proposition without proof, and I want some refence (not hartshorne) where I can read the proof of this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is not much dificult to see that  $I_Y$ is an ideal sheaf, the important thing here is see that is quasi-coherent.

Comment: Thanks, in this book appear exactly the theorem what I need, so will be read more, ejejejeje, so I need study more, thanks again.

Comment: I think that you have all the reason. thanks the best.

Comment: I have a bad habit of doing everything in the comments; I've tried to fix this below. Out of curiosity: what are you reading?

Comment: I´m reading about the Grothendieck ring of varieties for example this reference LEV A. BORISOV  and FRANZISKA BITTNER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give this an answer: there are proofs at [Stacks project tag 01QO](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QO) and in II, 5.9 of Hartshorne. The proof in Hartshorne is not so bad. I think most proofs will use two ingredients: $\textsf{QCoh}_X$ is an abelian subcategory of $\textsf{Mod}_X$; and if you have a morphism $f\colon X \to Y$ then the functor $f_*$ doesn't always take $\textsf{QCoh}_X$ to $\textsf{QCoh}_Y$, but it does if the morphism is affine or more generally if it is quasicompact.